# Wordpress search exact match

Tags: wp-query, search

I have a few search filters set up and I found a few posts that shouldn't be in the search results. On looking into it further I found these posts match 'part' of the keyword.

For example, searching for 'car' would match posts with 'carried', 'carbon', 'scar' and anything else with car in the word. I really want this to only pull posts that match 'car' exactly.

Is this how wordpress works by default? I've already tried the `'exact' => true` argument on WP_Query but that makes the search horribly specific when using category filters etc.

How can I set it so it matches keywords exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to append the query parameter `sentence=1` in your search, it is not well documented, but it should retrieve content inside the post that matches exactly the *sentence pattern*.

Alternatively, for a more powerful search, you might want to give a look at [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin. A lot of people agree that Wordpress search engine is… lacking, to say the least.