# Search for "2nd" also returns "22nd" in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm using `wp_query` to search a string:

```
$args = array('s' => '2nd','posts_per_page' => '-1',);
```

I'm looking for the 2nd of the month but it is also returning 22nd which is pragmatically correct, but logically incorrect as I only want the 2nd day and **not** all instances of a string `w` the word '2nd' in it (which is why '22nd' is included).

The word "2nd" is part of a paragraph so I don't think you can use

`$args = array('day' => '2nd','posts_per_page' => '-1',);`

because the instance of the word "2nd" isn't a date. It's in a paragraph as part of a string.

So is there a way to search on "2nd" and **not** return "22nd"?

Comment: This should work: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177183/make-a-wp-query-search-match-exactly-the-search-term